# win32api.GetUserNameEx() not working when converted to .exe

Tags: python

Why this code doesn't work when I convert it to exe with py2exe?

```
import os,win32api,win32con

user = win32api.GetUserNameEx (win32con.NameSamCompatible)
print user
os.system("PAUSE")
```

Maybe I'm just missing something very obvious here but I don't get it.

Edit: Someone answered this question and it worked perfectly but somehow his post got deleted. I just want to say... Thank you very much.

Comment: post what she/he had posted so that it can help others with the same problem in the future (post it as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
import os
username=os.getenv('username')
print
```